# Where to start with Linux?

Tags: linux

I am serious windows user with a background of almost ten year and a really small background in Ubuntu (+ lil bit of shell)

I have Linux Single Board Computers in mind and I wanna seriously learn C and Linux Where Should i Start ?

UPDATE: I asked a question got an answer! and it wasn't a novel or a book, just a website address and it really it was the answer. But Why I update the question is to say that if *someone* don't understand a question its not necessarily *Wrong*, and when sometimes People likes to Practice they are privileges it's is a bit obsessive, try to be open and understanding, sorry for my language.

Comment: Voting to close because this question can not be easily answered. The best advice I can give you is still "Just do it", there is no magical manual for Linux (well, as a matter of fact, there are such books...but they're are 1k+ pages if I remember right and still not complete). Learning it yourself and picking out what you need and leaving out what you do not need is still the best thing, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Bobby, but wil really answerd my question.

Comment: It's not about understanding the question. Sure, Wils answer answered **your** question, but it did not answer **the** question "Where to start with Linux". Though, it should have been closed as 'too localized' or 'subjective or argumentative' to reflect this.

Comment: @Bobby: The Question was _Where to start Linux With_ having single board Computers in mind, your an electro-mechanic I don't know how more specific this question should be for others to understand from your point of view as you vote for closing this because it can not be answered easily and By saying *YOUR* question was answered, I think that is the point I didn't ask for the whole world, anyways thanks for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "learn Linux" in particular and not just ubuntu, certainly the best place to start is [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/), it will allow you to get a much deeper understanding of the Linux kernel and how features fit around it.

If you then get stuck and have any particular problems, ask here on [Super User](http://www.superuser.com) or the [Linux Stack Exchange site!](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Linux From Scratch is jumping into the deep end a bit there. You might prefer to start with a distro that requires you to configure most things yourself, e.g. Arch Linux or Gentoo

Comment: @Starofale - I would argue that using Gentoo (not used Arch) makes you follow commands and do many things that you have no clue about - e.g. you are just following instructions without a deep understanding of how/why they work. The Linux from scratch manual is good and if you have a deep technical understanding, it has a lot of useful information that actually "teaches" linux at a deep level so that you can then use distributions such as Gentoo with the understanding of what every little thing does.